# how to restart an application 5 times with delay time 25min, through jenkins pipeline using groovy script

Tags: shell-script, docker, jenkins

How can I restart an application a total of 5 times with a 25 minute delay between each launch, through a jenkins pipeline using a groovy script?

```
//service update command need to execute..
stage('haproxy restart') {
   script{
 sh '''
docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy //5 times need to execute, delay between restart is 25 minutes.
  '''}
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is just repeat 5 times with delay in between then just repeat the command 5 times with sleep in between.

```
//service update command need to execute..
stage('haproxy restart') {
  script{
    sh '''
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy
      sleep 25m
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy
      sleep 25m
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy
      sleep 25m
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy
      sleep 25m
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy
    '''}
```

gnu sleep understands `25m` as 25 minutes. most if not all other sleeps take the number (if without letters) as number of seconds. if the sleep on your system does not understand letters then calculate 60 seconds times 25 minutes and use that number.

note that if done this way the entire command will block for the entire time (so at least 4 times 25 minutes plus however long the docker commands take). also note that i have little experience in jenkins. i do not know if that is a bad for the rest of the pipelines.

---

about the delay

is it delay from last return to next launch? or is it delay from last launch to next launch?

if the commands (docker in this case) merely takes seconds then it doesn't matter. but if the command takes minutes then you have take care of this extra time.

for example if the docker command takes about 5 minutes. then from first launch you have 5 minutes docker run time then 25 minutes sleep time until next launch. that is 30 minutes from launch to launch. this scenario is what you get with the code above.

alternatively if docker already ran for 5 minutes then sleep only 20 minutes for total time of 25 minutes from launch to next launch. luckily this is rather simple to achieve in shell code:

```
//service update command need to execute..
stage('haproxy restart') {
  script{
    sh '''
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy &
      sleep 25m
      wait
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy &
      sleep 25m
      wait
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy &
      sleep 25m
      wait
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy &
      sleep 25m
      wait
      docker service update --force abc-haproxy-${qa_env}-haproxy
    '''}
```

the ampersand (`&`) at the end makes the docker command execute in the background. the effect is that sleep will start executing "immediately" and will start to sleep parallel to the docker command. if the docker command takes 5 minutes then sleep already has slept 5 minutes and will continue to sleep 20 minutes for a total of 25 minutes from last launch.

"immediately" in quotes because there is always some microseconds delay due to bookkeeping of the operating system and whatnot. but those should be negligible in context of 25 minutes sleeps and only 5 repeats.

the last docker command has no ampersand (and thus not backgrounded) because we want to wait for that command to finish properly. otherwise jenkins might consider the stage as done even though the last docker command is still running (in background). again i have little experience in jenkins so do not know the intricate details of this.

the wait command makes sh wait for any background process until they are done before continuing with next command. it effectively cancels the ampersand. so if a docker command should take more than 25 minutes and the sleep is done sleeping then sh waits for that docker command to return before starting the next.

otherwise, without wait, if a docker command takes longer than 25 minutes then the sleep will be done and the next docker command starts parallel to the still running docker command. this might cause grievance as parallel running docker commands can starve the system of resources.

---

bonus:

you can put the command in a shell function for less repetition of code

```
//service update command need to execute..
stage('haproxy restart') {
  script{
    sh '''
      dodocker() {
        docker service update --force abc-haproxy-$1-haproxy
      }
      dodocker ${qa_env}
      sleep 25m
      dodocker ${qa_env}
      sleep 25m
      dodocker ${qa_env}
      sleep 25m
      dodocker ${qa_env}
      sleep 25m
      dodocker ${qa_env}
    '''}
```

you can write a loop for more flexibility with numbers of repeats

```
//service update command need to execute..
stage('haproxy restart') {
  script{
    sh '''
      dodocker() {
        docker service update --force abc-haproxy-$1-haproxy
      }
      seq ${repeat} | while read _ ; do
        dodocker ${qa_env}
        sleep 25m
      done
      dodocker ${qa_env}
    '''}
```

take care to set repeat to one less because the last dodocker iteration is not in the loop because it should not have a sleep afterwards.

and you can split the sleep in stages for human friendly log output

```
//service update command need to execute..
stage('haproxy restart') {
  script{
    sh '''
      dodocker() {
        docker service update --force abc-haproxy-$1-haproxy
      }
      seq ${repeat} | while read r ; do
        echo "repeat number $r"
        dodocker ${qa_env}
        seq ${delay} | while read d ; do
          echo "delay minute $d"
          sleep 1m
        done
      done
      dodocker ${qa_env}
    '''}
```

this way you can track the logfile and see how far along the process has been running. after all 4 times 25 minutes is almost 2 hours.